# Audio processing FFT of chunks of audio

Tags: fft, matlab

Im new to Matlab. I need to split the time dimensions of an audio track into frames of 10mS and for every 10mS frame have to compute the FFT to generate the spectrograph.
I need help on this.

Comment: I'm going to migrate this question to the signal processing.SE site. There will be a link that appears below the question here that you can follow to the new location of your question. If you need help creating an account on signal processing.SE, you can flag your question for moderator attention, and someone over there will help out.

Comment: This is called the short-time Fourier transform, or STFT. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform

Comment: MATLAB has a built-in `spectrogram` function. See [Hilmar's answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1166/6)

Comment: @ZevChonoles This does NOT belong here. This is more appropriate for StackOverflow because it is a **programming** question!

Answer (score 6):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/spectrogram.html

This pretty standard fare. For audio I would recommend a hanning() window and an overlap of half a window length so

```
x = randn(44100,1); % some random noise sample of a second
S = spectrogram(x,hanning(512),256); % short term FFT
```

Assuming a sample rate of 44.1 kHz this gives you frames about 11.6 ms length. You can get to exactly 10ms but that requires FFTs that are not a power of 2.

Comment: This is a very good answer. I just want to point out something somewhat unrelated -- often literature calls it a "Hanning" window, but really it is just a "Hann" window after Julius von Hann. It often gets called "Hanning" due to confusion with the Hamming window, but that terminology is incorrect. In any case though, the Hann window is a great general-purpose choice.